# Encrypting string with \t \r \n nodejs

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes

```
module.exports.crypt = async ({ secretKey, ivKey }, data) => {

 let encryptedData = {};
 for (key in data) {
   const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', secretKey, ivKey);
   encrypted = cipher.update(data[key]);
   encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
   encryptedData[key] = encrypted.toString('base64');
 }
  return encryptedData;
}
```

this code snippet works on normal encryption but when i tried encrypting ***'test\testemployee'*** the character ***'\t'*** gets omitted (same with "\n" "\r"). Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I strongly suspect somewhere in other code you are stripping these characters, either before encrypting or after decrypting. Print out `data[key]` before encryption, and then look at your decryption code and check the string immediately after decryption (before it is returned to something else that may modify it). Your bug is somewhere other than this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES in CBC mode doesn't care about what you encypt: it simply encrypts the bytes that you supply (after padding it to the right size in most implementations).

Does  `data[key]` contain the right characters? If so then you need to explicitly encode to e.g. UTF-8 before calling `update`. Otherwise you need to make sure that `data[key]` gets assigned the right value of course.

Note that using `let message = data[key]` followed by `encrypted = cipher.update(message)` would show you the contents of a message in the debugger; don't be hasty!

Comment: thank bro! data[key] was the omitting the special characters. I was iterating on a json object with {username: "test\test", password: "testpw"}